# Inconsistent behaviour of Click() in Selenium

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, nunit

I'm working on a Product automation(Web CMS), where **`element.Click()`** shows the inconsistent behaviour. Basically we are using,

*Selenium + Nunit GUI(unit testing framework)* - To run the test cases from local on a particular environment
*Selenium + Asp.net web application* - Multiple user's can run the test cases on different environment
Here environment I mean different levels(Dev, SIT, QA, Production).

**My Concern**
In one of my test cases, I want to Click a button. So for that, I have tried few code. But all are inconsistent behaviour. Here Inconsistent I mean, the code whatever I wrote for clicking a button are only working in my local or server and viceversa.

***1st attempt:-*** 
I tried all the element locator's

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("element id goes here"))
Working fine at my local, but not in server
```

***Result - Failed***

***2nd attempt:-***

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("Element XPath goes here")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Working fine at server, but not in local
Result - Failed

***3rd attempt:-***

```
IWebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("something"));
    IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
                        executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

Not working in both(local and server)
Result - Failed

At last, I tried waiting for the element to be visible and performing action

***4th attempt:-***

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("element xpath goes here")));
```

After webdriver wait performing action on that element **`(element.click())`**
Working fine at local but not in server
Result - Failed

I'm looking for a solution, ***where Clicking the button should not be an inconsistent behaviour.*** Basically it should work fine in both ***(Local and Server)***. Your help would be greatly appreciated..Thanks in advance
FYI - I'm testing in Mozilla Firefox browser 38.5.2

Comment: You never said what was the problem. "Failed" isn't a good description of a problem. Instead say what happened. Any exception? What happens?

Comment: I'm using Selenium in C# locally on Win7 and remotely on Win10 and MacOS with the Firefox browser

Comment: @ Sriram - Actually, when Clicking that particular button, Firefox pop-up blocker alert message got displayed, and it stopped executing the test cases..FYI - Even though pop-up blocker got disabled at the browser level

Comment: @ sriram - No exception is thrown..Because of the visibility of pop-up blocker window appears at the browser level, it is failing to execute

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Selenium in C# locally on Win7 and remotely on Win10 and MacOS with the Firefox browser and also noticed that Firefox sometimes requires special treatment for IWebElement.Click(). So I wrote myself an extension method, which works fine for me, no matter by what locator the element was found:

```
public static void Click(this IWebElement element, TestTarget target)
{
    if (target.IsFirefox)
    {
        var actions = new Actions(target.Driver);
        actions.MoveToElement(element);

        // special workaround for the FirefoxDriver
        // otherwise sometimes Exception: "Cannot press more then one button or an already pressed button"
        target.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.Zero);
        // temporarily disable implicit wait
        actions.Release().Build().Perform();
        target.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(MyDefaultTimeoutInSeconds));

        Thread.Sleep(500);
        actions.MoveToElement(element);
        actions.Click().Build().Perform();
    }
    else
    {
        element.Click();
    }
}
```

If you want more stable behavior for your test cases, I would recommend using ChromeDriver. It never needs **any** special treatment at all, and it's also much faster than the FirefoxDriver.

Comment: Getting an exception

Comment: Oops! That's correct. You have to put the line with `actions.Release().Build().Perform();` into `try` ... `catch{}` (ignoring any exception)